# Limit wordpress loop to 10 or 20 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the custom field plugin and i have made some custom fields in wordpress.

I wrote php to bring to the front the custom fields using the following code, but it doesn't stop looping and I need only 10 or 20 times to loop.

So I want to change but I don't know how.

```
<?php if( $banner_query2->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( $banner_query2->have_posts() ) : $banner_query2->the_post(); ?>
                
                    

<?php 
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        
        ?>
        <?php
            $featured_matches = get_field('locations');
            if( $featured_matches ): ?>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach( $featured_matches as $post ): 

                    // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
                    setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    
            <!--             <a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>"><?php //the_title(); ?></a> -->
            

                        <span><?php the_field( 'customfile' ); ?></span>
                        <span><?php the_field( 'customfile2' ); ?></span>
                        
                    
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php 
                // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
                    
                
            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: Yuk WP encourages you to write such unreadable code

Comment: I changed your post to talk about the actual problem rather then presuming what the correct solution will be - this is generally a much more productive way to ask questions.

Comment: Do we assume you want this `<?php foreach( $featured_matches as $post ):` forech loop limited to only run 10 or 20 times?

Comment: I dont know the limit. Cause it depends on the Api

Comment: So where is the API data in this code that will hold the limiting number

Comment: what API exactly? Perhaps you can get the value from this API and put the value it returns into `$cnt`, as per RiggsFolly's code below, and then continue as that answer suggests. It's hard to suggest anything better, since we know nothing about what this API is or why you can't already get the necessary value from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like in wordpress if you add just `break;` in the end of the foreach loop works fine

Answer (score 2):

Its quite possible to terminate a foreach loop or any other early, by using `break;` so all you need to do is maintain a counter and when it reaches the magic number `break` the loop.

```
<?php 
    $cnt = 0;
    $maxcnt = 10;
    foreach( $featured_matches as $post ): 

        // do your funky stuff

        $cnt++;
        if ( $cnt >= $maxcnt ) :
            break;
        endif;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: But i dont know the limit

Comment: Well if you dont know the limit and I cannot possibly guess the limit, what are we going to do??

Comment: So you have to call an API to get the limit, so do you already call it, or do you have to callit in this code?